# Docker: Django + MS SQL + Python 3.6?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, docker, dockerfile

I need to setup Django + MS SQL + Python 3.6 together on a Linux Docker container.

I ran the official [Docker Django + PostgreSQL](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) guide and everything is working fine, but when I switch to using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 as the database using the [django-pyodbc-azure](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/) driver, I get the error:

> localhost did not send data

I would appreciate any help or guidance on this.

```
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': 'SERVERNAME',
        'NAME': 'DATABASENAME',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            "driver": "FreeTDS",
            "host_is_server": True,
            "unicode_results": True,
            "extra_params": "tds_version=8.0",
        }
    }
}
```

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  # db:
  #   image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

```
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    tdsodbc
RUN apt-get install -y freetds-common freetds-bin freetds-dev
ADD odbcinst.ini /etc/
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pipenv install --system
# COPY . /code/
```

Comment: You might want to look into licensing when using mssql especially if you are going to spin up a bunch of these containers. I’m in the same boat as you (my work is stuck on mssql at least we are upgrading to 2016)

Comment: Hi, Daniel. I do not want to run a container with mssql. I want to connect to the SQL Server instance already available that I can normally access using SQL Server Management Studio. Any ideas?

Comment: Gotcha. No I don’t. I haven’t gone down that path yet. I plan I’m doing it in the next few weeks though. I’ll come back to check your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you talk to mysql over port 8000?
Try specifying that port in your Database config if you do.  Mysql normally uses port 3306 so maybe try somthing like

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': 'SERVERNAME',
        'NAME': 'DATABASENAME',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            "driver": "FreeTDS",
            "host_is_server": True,
            "unicode_results": True,
            "extra_params": "tds_version=8.0",
        }
    }
}
```

You will also need to specify this in your docker compose

```
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  # db:
  #   image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "3306:3306"
```